# Kitten eating clumping litter

Tags: cats, toilet-training, safety

I just got a new kitten, 7 weeks old. He has been in the house for about 2-3 days and has gone pee multiple times and pooped once. He is litter trained, but he has been chewing on litter. I am unsure if he has been swallowing this litter and how often he chews on it. I cannot see a vet until next month. When should I be worried about this litter blocking his system? Is this a common or does this easily occur with a few grains?

Comment: He has been very energetic and eating well

Comment: It may be because he is teething. Get him something to chew on so that he can soothe his gums.

Comment: Why can you not see a vet til next month? that's a crazy wait! If it's because you can't afford to, you should be considering if you should really have a kitten however.

Answer (score 7):

It's not unusual for kittens to chew on litter - especially if teething (as Mick referred to in his comment). Try providing him with easy access to something else to chew on (you can get chewy kitten "treats" designed for just this) and in the meantime I'd change the litter to a non-clumping variety immediately - even if he is not trying to "eat" the litter there remains a risk that he will swallow some and clumping litter can be quite harmful if swallowed.

Comment: So I Have this same problem, we adopted this sick cat temporarily to see if we can cure her ,she gave birth to a boy and a girl, which are 4 weeks old now , without training they started using litter to pee from 2days ago, but tonight i noticed the boy is chewing and even might have swallowed a couple of the grains, now i can't go to the wet until Saturday, and regarding the brand, the problem is here we only have 10Kg packagings , so trying out different brands will cost us a lot , plus that we own another cat prior to this, any other way to prevent this, they already know to use it to pee

Answer (score 3):

My parents dogs (which are litter trained) did that, too. So we changed the kind of the litter. We found a brand they did not eat, so everything is fine know.

Eating litter is something you should worry about, especially when it is clumping litter, because it can block his system. This depends on how much he is eating. So you should observe him until you found a brand you are sure he is not eating, and stop him whenever you see him chewing on the litter. A small amount should not be harmful, so don't panic, but watch him carefully.

Does he eat and drink enough? Is he active? Has he alternatives to chew on and enough to eat? If you see any changes in his behavior, e.g. he is calmer and stops  eating and drinking, than you have to go immediately to the vet. But if he is acting fine, you should not worry too much.